# What format is /etc/shadow in?

Tags: linux, passwords

I'm currently trying to recreate the shadow hash + format on the web (for CTF challenges and things that may require recreating shadow passwords, or breaking *very* simple ones -- I use a Chromebook quite a lot so having it on the web is great for me), and I'm unsure what format the passcodes in /etc/shadow are in. My current knowledge is that it's, of course, a hash (depending on the `$x$` version), with a salt (`$x$salt`), and then a hash `$x$salt$hash` in base64 with a custom alphabet -- I'm unsure if that information is correct or what alphabet it uses -- I already have the hashes down, but the encoding it uses is the part that is tricking me.

As you can try out, online hash encoders don't produce the same hashes as the ones used in /etc/shadow, which is my current format issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: You should have [edited your original question so it could be reopened](https://superuser.com/questions/1717714/what-custom-format-is-etc-shadow-encoded-in) rather than reposting essentially the same question.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm quite new to how this works, so I assumed that editing the post wouldn't un-remove it.

Comment: @DavidPostill I mentioned in my question  I'm trying to recreate a shadow *format, will reword as hash in the web. I'll still edit it for more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These hashes are created with the crypt(3) function. While originally this function was part of libc, nowadays the [libxcrypt](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt) library provides it in new Linux distributions and comes with a [crypt(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libcrypt-dev/crypt.5.en.html) manual page somewhat describing the formats that it supports.

First note that, for example, although `$5$` is described as "SHA-256" it *isn't* really plain SHA-256, it's something called "sha256crypt" which involves several thousand rounds of SHA-256 (apparently it was based on PBKDF1) as can be seen [in the source](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/blob/develop/lib/crypt-sha256.c#L159). So even if you add the salt correctly, plain SHA-256 hashers will never produce the correct result.

Both the salt and the hash use Base64 with a slightly custom alphabet. But in the same source code, you can see that at least for some algorithms, the salt *isn't* decoded before using – for `$5$SaLt$hAsH`, the whole `SaLt$` directly gets used as the salt. This may vary – bcrypt *does* decode the salt, for example.